# Fixing "file can't be downloaded securely" error in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, security, download

When I download `.pdf` files from a specific website by using Google Chrome, I get the error message `file can't be downloaded securely`.

I looked for solutions and I found two options:

- set no protection in the section [chrome://settings/security](https://chrome://settings/security)
- enable the option in the figure below (I wrote the name of the website into the box):

[image]

---

EDIT
[image]

These methods do not fix the problem; can you tell me how to overcome it please?

---

EDIT 2: I right click on the bottom to download the PDF file anf then I get the error, instead, if I open the webpage by left clicking on the botton, I can see and download the PDF.

[image]

---

EDIT 3
Image of the webpage where there is the button to go to the pdf
[image]

Image of the webpage with the pdf opened
[image]

Comment: From which site are you downloading those PDFs?

Comment: Hello @Gantendo it's the website of my university so I logged in to access to the files.

Comment: Go to `chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure` and then add the URL of the place the PDFs are hosted to the box on the left hand side, then choose Enabled on the right hand side, then try again https://i.imgur.com/VYps15a.png

Comment: And maybe tell your University that they need HTTPs.

Comment: It is quite likely that Firefox will allow you to download those files, and it is a better browser; you might wanna give that a try.

Comment: @Gantendo I did it, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Usually you can just override the security warning on the web page if you're sure that the source is secure. Could you show what exactly do you have on the download page (hide sensitive data if needed)?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi you added the website of the University or the website address where the files are coming from? Those are probably not the same. On the Downloads pages in Chrome you can see the URL/website the download is being pulled from.

Comment: Hello @YisroelTech I added the website where the pdf are.

Comment: To be honest, the 'problem' isn't yours to fix, it the website developers that need to fix their website. Why isn't the Keep option good enough for your use?

Comment: click on the up-arrow on the "can't be downloaded securely" message and then there's an option to "keep."

Comment: @YisroelTech the keep option is a bit boring because I need to download hundreds of files.

Comment: And if you right-click the link to the PDF file and copy it to the clipboard, then paste it in your favorite text editor and change http:// to https:// and then copypaste the result in the addressbar of your browser?

Comment: Have you tried Firefox?

Comment: It's a possibility you didn't put the URL correctly, but it's impossible to catch such potential issues without screenshots of the download page with the URL and the flag with the website there

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi if you need hundreds of files (should include such info in the question) then ask the website to fix their certificate, university should set a good example when it comes to security. It's not really safe to turn off browser security when doing a batch download. What if just 1 of the files was a virus that's not detected by your AV?

Comment: You should [edit] your question to clarify the information we are asking about, I would agree, creating an exception to the security rule within Chrome or using a different browser is the solution to your problem. Saying “it’s not your problem to fix”, while technically correct, and I totally agree with the statement isn’t exactly helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The party to ***fix*** the issue is the website owner/developer, not you. So make sure to contact them about it.

That being said, you should be able to do some workaround to allow it (for this site only, as completely disabling the feature is certainly not advised.) But it's a bit difficult to guide you very specifically without having the context how the actual URL of the PDF looks like (and on what site it's loaded from.)

Try those two:

1. Allow "Insecure content" on the host site:

   - On the host site you're downloading from, click the **padlock** next to the address bar and go to **Site settings**
   - Scroll down to **Insecure content** and change it to ***Allow***
   - Go back to the site and Reload the page
   - Try again to download the PDF
2. Add the PDF URL website to have "Insecure origins treated as secure":

   - Click to download one such file, and go to the Downloads page (where it shows the download and gives you an option to Keep the file)
   - Right-click the link there and do ***Copy Link Address*** (to get something like `http://example.com/folder/example.pdf`
   - Go to `chrome://flags/#unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure`
   - For the first result (the **Insecure origins treated as secure**) change it to ***Enabled***
   - On the box under it, add the website part of the URL you copied earlier, including the http. Something like `http://example.com`
   - Click on the **Relaunch** on the bottom of that page to restart Chrome (as the changes will take effect the next time you relaunch Chrome)
   - Go back to the website and try downloading the PDF again

Comment: I tried and the result is the same; the point (1.) is not possible because the site is seen as secure if I open the link of the PDF in the browser, instead I'm downloading the PDF by saving the hyperlink of the PDF on another webpage.

Comment: Not sure what you're saying, and this reiterates the fact that it's impossible to address "your specific situation" while you try hiding the details. You should post screenshots of each step with the least info censored, and describe step by step what you are doing and what you see.

Comment: Hi @YisroelTech see the 2nd edit please.

Comment: The edit doesn't address any of the questions I asked to see, simply seeing a page with a button doesn't tell me anything.

Comment: To your point in the first comment here, I'm not sure what you're saying. Are you saying that you wasn't able to set this setting as instructed? If that's what you're saying, can you explain in more detail why?

Comment: I cannot follow the point (1.) in your reply because the webpages are all secure (see edit 3 please).

Comment: The fact that it is secure (the main website where the download button is) doesn't take away anything from following what I wrote in the first option. In the first image in Edit 3 I can see the **Site settings** option, click on that and follow what I wrote

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @YisroelTech, the point (1.) saved me.

Comment: Note in Edge you select Permissons for this site and in modern Chrome you click the Tune icon at the left of the URL.